# How do I add up values from different columns based on a condition of the column right next to it?

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out how to add up values from multiple columns based on the condition of another column adjacent to those columns.

I've tried using UNION for the columns but I haven't figured out the best way to go about it, and I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct way, because I get stuck from here.

```
select [Produce 1], [Weight 1] as columns from table
union
select [Produce 2], [Weight 2] from table
```

From my sample data:

```
Produce 1 | Weight 1 | Produce 2 | Weight 2     
Apples    | 2.2      | Oranges   | 5.1    
Oranges   | 3.1      | Apples    | 1.7
```

I would like my output to look something like this:

```
Produce | TotalWeight    
Apples  | 3.9    
Oranges | 8.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subquery and aggregation come to mind:

```
select produce, sum(weight)
from (select [Produce 1] as produce, [Weight 1] as weight from table
      union all
      select [Produce 2], [Weight 2] from table
     ) t
group by produce;
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` is probably the better choice here as I guess they don't want to have one lot of oranges (or apples) out should the weight happens to be the same in both.

Comment: @stickybit . . . I agree.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, both! Yes, I used Union All because of that. Greatly appreciate it!